Problems installing Ubuntu throu pen drive
I'm new to this, and I tried following some tutorials, but it didn't work very well.
I have a sister in the programming field, and she needs to install the Linux system, and they recommended using Ubuntu, so I did some research on how to install and download another application, balenaEtcher, to help. To do this, I need to use a ‘pen’ ‘drive’, and I did. One with 100 GB. I tried it first on my personal computer, and it worked fine, but the pen drive became unusable afterward, so I formatted it using CMD and emptied it completely, it looked brand new and ready to use. But, when trying to do the procedure on my sister's computer, it says that I needed to format the pen. I formatted it again, about 2 times, and it always did this. I don't know what it could be, I don't want to use another pen to "ruin" it.
If you could help me, I would appreciate.
Thank you and good day for you.

If it's Windows complaining that something needs to be formatted, then everything is fine; a Live usb contains a filesystem that Windows is unable to deal with, hence the complain. Just try and boot from the usb. About the "unuseable drive" after a successful boot, well, I've had that several times throughout the years, and to this date, I have no clue what's the deal with that.

It is normal that the whole drive will be unusable for other purposes if you turn it into a Live Ubuntu Installation USB using Belena Etcher or other similar tools. I recommend a smaller drive (16 GB should do fine). I recommend you keep the converted USB as is for future use. The "Try Ubuntu" option may come handy later if the installed version of Ubuntu becomes corrupted for some reason. The content of the immediately. Live Ubuntu Installation USB is not readable by Windows. Windows does not understand it and will want to format it.

Many of the tools that create a USB flash drive installer, create a hybrid DVD/flash drive configuration that does not have standard partitions. You often then have to use dd ot clear partition table area of misc data that makes drive look corrupted. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive &
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection You do not need to erase entire drive, but partition table area. If using a larger drive note that installer erases entire drive.

Sometimes a pendrive is ruined/bricked/damaged beyond repair, but most of the time there is only confusion, either because you let Windows fail to read something made for Linux or simply because the file system is corrupted. In such cases you can re-use the pendrive after creating a new partition table and file system. See also this link.

This question is similar to: How to restore original size and unboot my bootable USB pendrive. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
